# How to perform a touch and hold gesture using AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, android-studio, accessibilityservice

```
Path clickPath = new Path();
clickPath.moveTo(x, y);
GestureDescription.StrokeDescription clickStroke = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, 1);
GestureDescription.Builder clickBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
clickBuilder.addStroke(clickStroke);
dispatchGesture(clickBuilder.build(), null, null);
```

With this code I can perform clicks anywhere on the screen. Is there any way to perform touch and hold gesture using AccessibilityService?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to perform touch and hold gesture using AccessibilityService?

I think that you need decide if the gesture [`willContinue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/GestureDescription.StrokeDescription.html#GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(android.graphics.Path,%20long,%20long,%20boolean)) or not. Then, based in your code i suggest change:

```
GestureDescription.StrokeDescription clickStroke = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, 1);
```

To:

```
GestureDescription.StrokeDescription clickStroke = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, 1, true);
```

Simply, add `true` to last parameter of `StrokeDescription`. **PS**: this works only from Android 8+.

Comment: I tried this, it is working in Android 10 and Android 11 but not working in Android 12.